# why DELETE METHOD is not working in MERN STACK blog application?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jwt, mern

In my blog site everything is okay but the Delete is not working and it's saying : 401 invalid JWT

I think everything is okay and its still doing all the other jobs perfectly like the edit blog or create blog. And I don't think I should get any error. Even It''s sending the request to the server.

my BlogDetails.jsx::

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";
import '../CSS/details.css';
import {format} from'date-fns';
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";

const BlogDetails = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const {id} = useParams();
    const [blogInfo, setBlogInfo] = useState(null);
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const {userInfo} = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/blogs/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                response.json()
                    .then(blogInfo => {
                        setBlogInfo(blogInfo);
                        console.log(blogInfo);
                    })
            })
    }, [id]);

    const handleDelete = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/blogs/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
            });
    
            if (response.ok) {
                setRedirect(true);
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to delete the blog:', response.status);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during delete request:', error);
        }
    };
    

    if (!blogInfo) return '';
    if(redirect) {
        history.push('/')
    }
    return (  
        <div className="blog-details">
            <div className="title">
                <h1>{blogInfo.title}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="date">
                <time>First Published On {format(new Date(blogInfo.createdAt), 'MMM d, yyyy  h:mm:ss aa')}</time>
                <br />
                <time>Last Updated On {format(new Date(blogInfo.updatedAt), 'MMM d, yyyy h:mm aa')}</time>
            </div>
            <div className="edit">
                {userInfo.id === blogInfo.author._id && (
                    <div className="buttons">
                        <button><Link to={`/edit/${blogInfo._id}`}>Edit This Blog</Link></button>
                        <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete This Blog</button>
                    </div>
                )} 
            </div>
            <div className="author">
                <p>by @{blogInfo.author.username}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="image">
                <img src={`http://localhost:4000/${blogInfo.file}`} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:blogInfo.content}}></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}
 
export default BlogDetails;
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/User');
const Blog = require('./models/Blog')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const fs = require('fs');

const saltRounds = 10;
const secret = 'hdskjfj49353kjdfsdjf';
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/BLOGAPP').then(()=> {
    console.log('Connected to mongo DB');
    app.listen(4000)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}))
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))

app.post('/signup', (req, res)=> {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    const user = new User ({
        username, 
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds)
    });
    user.save()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Registration successful' });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });
});

app.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
        // User not found
        res.status(400).json('User not found');
        return;
    }
    const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    if (passOk) {
        jwt.sign({ username, id: user._id }, secret, (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
            } else {
                res.cookie('token', token).json({
                    id: user._id,
                    username,
                })               
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json('Wrong credentials');
    }
});


app.post('/logout', (req, res)=> {
    res.cookie('token', '').json('ok')
})

app.get('/blogs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const blogs = await Blog.find()
            .populate('author', 'username')
            .sort({createdAt : -1})
            .limit(20);
            res.json(blogs);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.cookies;

    if (!token) {
        // Token not provided
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT must be provided' });
        return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            // Invalid token
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
        } else {
            res.json(info);
        }
    });
});


app.post('/new_blog', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const {originalname, path} = req.file;
    const part = originalname.split(".");
    const ext = part[part.length -1];
    const newPath = path+'.'+ext;
    fs.renameSync(path, newPath);

    // Check if token exists
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT must be provided' });
        return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            return;
        }

        const { title, snippet, content } = req.body;

        const blog = new Blog({
            title,
            snippet,
            content,
            file: newPath,
            author: info.id,
        });

        try {
            // Save the blog and wait for the promise to resolve
            const savedBlog = await blog.save();
            res.json(savedBlog);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const Details = await Blog.findById(id).populate('author', ["username"]);

    if (!Details) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Blog not found' });
    }
    res.json(Details);
});

app.put('/blogs/:id', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const newPath = req.file ? req.file.path : null;

    const { token } = req.cookies;

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            return;
        }

        try {
            const { title, content, snippet } = req.body;
            const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

            if (!blog) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
                return;
            }

            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
                return;
            }

            blog.title = title;
            blog.content = content;
            blog.snippet = snippet;

            if (newPath) {
                blog.file = newPath;
            }

            const updatedBlog = await blog.save();
            res.json(updatedBlog);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
});

app.delete('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

        if (!blog) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
        }

        const { token } = req.cookies;

        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            }

            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
            }

            // Remove the associated file (if it exists)
            if (blog.file) {
                fs.unlinkSync(blog.file);
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return res.json({ message: 'Blog deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
app.delete('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

        if (!blog) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
        }

        const { token } = req.cookies;

        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('JWT Verification Error:', err);
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            }
            console.log('JWT Verified Successfully:', info);
            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
            }

            // Remove the associated file (if it exists)
            if (blog.file) {
                fs.unlinkSync(blog.file);
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return res.json({ message: 'Blog deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/User');
const Blog = require('./models/Blog')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const fs = require('fs');

const saltRounds = 10;
const secret = 'hdskjfj49353kjdfsdjf';
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/BLOGAPP').then(()=> {
    console.log('Connected to mongo DB');
    app.listen(4000)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}))
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))

app.post('/signup', (req, res)=> {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    const user = new User ({
        username, 
        password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds)
    });
    user.save()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Registration successful' });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });
});

app.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
        // User not found
        res.status(400).json('User not found');
        return;
    }
    const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    if (passOk) {
        jwt.sign({ username, id: user._id }, secret, (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
            } else {
                res.cookie('token', token).json({
                    id: user._id,
                    username,
                })               
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json('Wrong credentials');
    }
});


app.post('/logout', (req, res)=> {
    res.cookie('token', '').json('ok')
})

app.get('/blogs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const blogs = await Blog.find()
            .populate('author', 'username')
            .sort({createdAt : -1})
            .limit(20);
            res.json(blogs);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.cookies;

    if (!token) {
        // Token not provided
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT must be provided' });
        return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            // Invalid token
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
        } else {
            res.json(info);
        }
    });
});


app.post('/new_blog', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const {originalname, path} = req.file;
    const part = originalname.split(".");
    const ext = part[part.length -1];
    const newPath = path+'.'+ext;
    fs.renameSync(path, newPath);

    // Check if token exists
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT must be provided' });
        return;
    }

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            return;
        }

        const { title, snippet, content } = req.body;

        const blog = new Blog({
            title,
            snippet,
            content,
            file: newPath,
            author: info.id,
        });

        try {
            // Save the blog and wait for the promise to resolve
            const savedBlog = await blog.save();
            res.json(savedBlog);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const Details = await Blog.findById(id).populate('author', ["username"]);

    if (!Details) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Blog not found' });
    }
    res.json(Details);
});

app.put('/blogs/:id', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const newPath = req.file ? req.file.path : null;

    const { token } = req.cookies;

    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            return;
        }

        try {
            const { title, content, snippet } = req.body;
            const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

            if (!blog) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
                return;
            }

            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
                return;
            }

            blog.title = title;
            blog.content = content;
            blog.snippet = snippet;

            if (newPath) {
                blog.file = newPath;
            }

            const updatedBlog = await blog.save();
            res.json(updatedBlog);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    });
});

app.delete('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

        if (!blog) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
        }

        const { token } = req.cookies;

        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            }

            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
            }

            // Remove the associated file (if it exists)
            if (blog.file) {
                fs.unlinkSync(blog.file);
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return res.json({ message: 'Blog deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
app.delete('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

        if (!blog) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
        }

        const { token } = req.cookies;

        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('JWT Verification Error:', err);
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            }
            console.log('JWT Verified Successfully:', info);
            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
            }

            // Remove the associated file (if it exists)
            if (blog.file) {
                fs.unlinkSync(blog.file);
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return res.json({ message: 'Blog deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
```

I am trying to create a DELETE method for my blog site but it's not working

Comment: check if token is getting sent in request cookies , check in network tab in browser

Comment: @DarshanPatel No payload for this request its saying

Comment: @MurtazaAbdullah You need to check the **headers** section of the request for request cookies, not payload. Check if there is a cookie value for the `token`.

Comment: Aren't you missing `credentials: 'include'` in the `fetch()` options? Otherwise, cookies will not be sent

Comment: @MurtazaAbdullah not payload cookies , in headers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to add

```
credentials : 'include',
```

to the `fetch()` request
Here is the updated code:

```
    import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";
import '../CSS/details.css';
import {format} from'date-fns';
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";

const BlogDetails = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const {id} = useParams();
    const [blogInfo, setBlogInfo] = useState(null);
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    const {userInfo} = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/blogs/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                response.json()
                    .then(blogInfo => {
                        setBlogInfo(blogInfo);
                        console.log(blogInfo);
                    })
            })
    }, [id]);

    const handleDelete = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/blogs/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
                credentials: "include",
            });
    
            if (response.ok) {
                setRedirect(true);
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to delete the blog:', response.status);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during delete request:', error);
        }
    };
    

    if (!blogInfo) return '';
    if(redirect) {
        history.push('/')
    }
    return (  
        <div className="blog-details">
            <div className="title">
                <h1>{blogInfo.title}</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="date">
                <time>First Published On {format(new Date(blogInfo.createdAt), 'MMM d, yyyy  h:mm:ss aa')}</time>
                <br />
                <time>Last Updated On {format(new Date(blogInfo.updatedAt), 'MMM d, yyyy h:mm aa')}</time>
            </div>
            <div className="edit">
                {userInfo.id === blogInfo.author._id && (
                    <div className="buttons">
                        <button><Link to={`/edit/${blogInfo._id}`}>Edit This Blog</Link></button>
                        <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete This Blog</button>
                    </div>
                )} 
            </div>
            <div className="author">
                <p>by @{blogInfo.author.username}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="image">
                <img src={`http://localhost:4000/${blogInfo.file}`} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:blogInfo.content}}></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}
 
export default BlogDetails;
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there are multiple instances of the DELETE route for '/blogs/:id' in your code. The issue may be related to the fact that the second and third instances of the route handler override the first one.

**You may try to Remove the redundant code and keep only one instance of the DELETE route handler.** Here's the corrected code:

```
app.delete('/blogs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(id);

        if (!blog) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Blog not found' });
        }

        const { token } = req.cookies;

        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('JWT Verification Error:', err);
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid JWT' });
            }

            const isAuthor = blog.author.toString() === info.id;

            if (!isAuthor) {
                return res.status(403).json({ message: 'You are not the author' });
            }

            // Remove the associated file (if it exists)
            if (blog.file) {
                fs.unlinkSync(blog.file);
            }

            await Blog.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return res.json({ message: 'Blog deleted successfully' });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
```

Make sure to remove the second and third instances of `app.delete('/blogs/:id', ...)` to avoid conflicts. After making these changes, try again to see if the DELETE method works as expected.